# How do I format a number to 2 decimal places, but only if there are already decimals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, decimal

I have a jQuery 1.5+ script, and you select a quantity in a drop-down menu (1,2,3, etc) and it multiplies that quantity by $1.50 to show you a total price. Basically - it's multiplying the quantity selected (1, 2, 3, etc) by the base price of $1.50 - BUT - I can't figure out how to display the price correctly with decimals - example: if you select a quantity of 2, the price displays correctly as $3 (no decimals). But, if you choose 1, or 3, the price displays as $1.5 / $4.5 - missing a 0 in the hundredths decimal place.

Here's the code - any idea how to show a second 0 in the case that there are not already two decimals? $3 should stay as $3, but $4.5 should become $4.50, etc - I can't get it to work without showing ALL numbers to two decimals, and that's where I'm stuck!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
    $(function() {         
        $('#myQuantity').change(function() {             
            var x = $(this).val();                      
            $('#myAmount').text('$'+(x*1.5));// this is the part that isn't displaying decimals correctly!
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

I'm experimenting with something like result = num.toFixed(2); but can't get it to work yet.

Thank you Kindly!

Comment: In what way does "toFixed(2)" not work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/JxPZH/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemQuantitySelect_3').change(function() {
        
        var itemPrice = 1.50;
        var itemQuantity = $(this).val();
        var quantityPrice = (itemPrice * itemQuantity);
        if(Math.round(quantityPrice) !== quantityPrice) {
            quantityPrice = quantityPrice.toFixed(2);
        }
        
        $(this).next("span").html("$" + quantityPrice);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <select id='itemQuantitySelect_3' name="itemQuantity_3">
        <option value='1'>1 Item</option>
        <option value='2'>2 Items</option>
        <option value='3'>3 Items</option>
    </select>
    <span>$1.50</span>
</form>
```

Comment: An answer really ought to include the code *in the answer* rather than just a link to jsfiddle with no explanation or comment.

Answer (score 98):

This should do the job:

```
var formattedNumber = (x * 1.5).toFixed(2).replace(/[.,]00$/, "");
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Removing the *1,5 makes this a great reusable codeline

Comment: Why the comma in the RegEx?

Comment: @merlinpatt Decimal separator can vary depending on the locale

Comment: `/[.,]0+$/ ` seems to be a better general solution.

Comment: Works well, but doesn't work for 0.30 => 0.3

Answer (score 45):

I suggest:

```
Math.round(floatNumber*100)/100;
```

It automatically adds 0, 1 or 2 decimal places.

Comment: this does not work. If `floatNumber` is `4.5`, the output is still `4.5`, instead the OP wants `4.50`

Answer (score 31):

How about

```
var str = num.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00$/, '');
```

Comment: This is nice and sweet and works for every possible input: `2  ->  2`, `4.5  ->  4.50`, `0.3242  ->  0.32`, `NaN  ->  NaN`, `-0.546  ->  -0.55`.

Answer (score 15):

```js
const number = Number(Number(value).toFixed(t));
```

With this you can cast your number to the correct amount of decimal places and, when converting back to Number, get rid of all useless zeros.

Comment: This is a neat solution as well. Works for 1.10 => 1.1 / 1.00 => 1 / 0.0001 => 0 / 0.00 => 0

Comment: This is the right solution imo.

Answer (score 9):

Use this function:

```
//E.g. 0.5 becomes 0.50; 7 stays as 7.

function twoDecimalPlacesIfCents(amount){
    return (amount % 1 !== 0) ? amount.toFixed(2) : amount;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

if a number%1 does not return zero, it is not an integer.

```
//var s='123';
var s='1.2';

s=Number(s);
alert(s%1? s.toFixed(2): s);
```

Comment: There is a wrinkle here where this answer would give a different result to the other answers using `replace`. For example, if `s = 1.001`, then this would give your the result `1.00`, where as the `replace` approach would give you `1`.  Which is more correct really depends on what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

`parseFloat(Number(25).toFixed(2))`

```js
const input1 = 1;
const input2 = 1.1;
const input3 = 1.12;
const input4 = 1.123
const input5 = 1.0;
const input6 = 1.00;


const output1 = parseFloat(Number(input1).toFixed(2));
const output2 = parseFloat(Number(input2).toFixed(2));
const output3 = parseFloat(Number(input3).toFixed(2));
const output4 = parseFloat(Number(input4).toFixed(2));
const output5 = parseFloat(Number(input5).toFixed(2));
const output6 = parseFloat(Number(input6).toFixed(2));

console.log("input: " + input1 + " output: " + output1);
console.log("input: " + input2 + " output: " + output2);
console.log("input: " + input3 + " output: " + output3);
console.log("input: " + input4 + " output: " + output4);
console.log("input: " + input5 + " output: " + output5);
console.log("input: " + input6 + " output: " + output6);
```

`

Answer (score 2):

```
value % 1 !== 0 ? value.toFixed(2) : value;
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.

Comment: @Shree What this code is saying value % 1 !== 0 if the remainder of value does not equal zero show value.toFixed(2), else show value only (without decimal).

Answer (score 1):

If you want more generic solution, based on [odrm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5623195/11951324) idea.

```
function toFixed(value, fractionDigits) {
    return value.toFixed(fractionDigits).replace(/[.,](00)|0$/, '')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const getPercentage = (partialValue, totalValue) => {
    return ((100 * partialValue) / totalValue).toFixed(2).replace(/[.,]00$/, "");
  };
```

You can just use this function, and call it wherever you want to

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(<number>);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility, coerce the string into a number and leverage the fact that  0.00 is falsey to determine how it displays:

```
+(1.123456.toFixed(2)) || 0;
>> 1.12
```

Where as:

```
+(0.00123.toFixed(2)) || 0;
>> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a much more dynamic solution to achieve this. This is useful especially when your number of digits will change.

```
var formattedNumber = (x * 1.5).toFixed(2).replace(/\.0+$|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$/, "");
```

This will end up to this:

```
+(2.1234).toFixed(2).replace(/\.0+$|(\.\d*[1-9]);
>> 2.12

// but as mentioned it is dynamic
+(2.1234).toFixed(3).replace(/\.0+$|(\.\d*[1-9]);
>> 2.123

+(2).toFixed(3).replace(/\.0+$|(\.\d*[1-9]);
>> 2
```

Comment: I like the idea, but the code is not working because of the ".0" character in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Javascripts built in number formatting object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

```
const yourNumber = 75.00
const formattedNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'USD',
     maximumFractionDigits: 2, 
    minimumFractionDigits: 0, 
}).format(yourNumber)
console.log(formattedNumber); // $75
```